# Op amp design that gives Vout(t) = (2V1 + 3V2 )− V3

Tags: operational-amplifier

Hello everyone in the community! I'm facing a challenge with a circuit I recently built and I'm having a hard time getting the expected results. The circuit in question involves amplifiers, and the Vout(t) output should be 13V, but I'm only getting 11V. The calculation for Vout(t) is given by Vout(t) = (2V1 + 3V2) − V3. I've gone over the component hookup, checked the amp specs, but still can't figure out what's causing this discrepancy. If anyone can offer me guidance, tips or suggestions for resolving this issue, I would be immensely grateful. Any help is welcome, and I'm willing to provide more details about the circuit if needed. Thanks in advance!
[image]
v1 = 4V, v2 = 2V and v3 = 1V

Comment: FYI your solution has 4 more op-amps than necessary; one should suffice.

Comment: It is possible, that your OpAmps cannot provide enough current to drive the 1 kohm load (R9 and R13). Try to use 10 kohm there.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your simulated op-amps are limiting at (or near) the simulation's supply rails. Try increasing the supplies to +/-15V.

Comment: I modified the voltages to higher values, however the measured output voltage does not change.

Comment: What happens if you reduce each of the input voltages to 1/2 ?